# mongodb C# drive query with string field be contained for string arg

Tags: c#, mongodb

mongodb data:

```
{
    name: "ccc"
}
```

C# drive:

```
string arg = "xxx ccc vvvv";
var match = from d in collection.AsQueryable<AAA>()
            where arg.Contains(d.name)
            select d;
```

i know it's impossible to perform.
how can i do something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the nature of your query, Mongo would need to visit every document in the collection and do a potentially expensive operation.

You can't use a regular expression efficiently as you're trying to do a contains match in a way that isn't supported. You're trying to query whether any given value in the field is contained within a string. You could only pass a pattern. So, if you knew that it was always a particular set of characters or in a certain way, you'd need to write an expression that specifically looked for it. Given your sample, that may not be possible.

You could use the `$where` operator by constructing JavaScript:

```
var arg = "xxx ccc vvvv";
var match = Query.Where(new BsonJavaScript("' + arg + '.indexOf(this.Name) > -1"));
```

I don't believe that you can use a `BsonJavaScript` object with LINQ yet though. You'd need to use the dynamic expression builders:

```
var results = collection.Find(match);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions

```
var regex = new Regex("xxx ccc vvvv");
var query =
    from d in collection.AsQueryable<AAA>()
    where regex.IsMatch(d.Name)
    select d;
```

Comment: That wouldn't work for the sample data. The Regular expression he needs is inverted  -- is the `Name` inside the string which would require the Regular Expression to be built from the value stored in the field.

Answer (score 0):

Split your string into an array of individual values to enable LINQ to efficiently execute the query using `$in`:

```
string arg = "xxx ccc vvvv";
var match = from d in collection.AsQueryable<AAA>()
            where arg.Split().Contains(d.name)
            select d;
```